# Converting "Stream<String>" to "String" in java8 to combine group of strings in a stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to convert `Stream<String>` to `String` and print all the string.

```
Stream<String> result= Stream.of("do","re","ma","po","fa","si")
                             .filter(str -> str.length()>5)
                             .peek(System.out:: println);
                           //.allMatch(str -> str.length() >5);

System.out.println(result);
```

**Here down output i get**

> java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter@63961c42

The result is printing an `object` but not a `String` and while converting to `toString()` also printing the same but how to print as a String

Answer (score 2):

In java 8, there is method [**joining()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html), Which is the part of [**Collectors class**](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors). You have to join this string using `Collectors.joining()`.

Here down is code:

```
String result = Stream.of("do", "re", "ma", "po", "fa", "si")
                .filter(str -> str.length() > 1)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Or

```
String result= Stream.of("do","re","ma","po","fa","si")
                .filter(str -> str.length() > 1)
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you looking for something like this?

```
    String result = Stream.of("do","re","ma","po","fa","si").
                collect(Collectors.joining(""));
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
doremapofasi
```

Or:

```
        String result = Stream.of("do", "re", "ma", "po", "fa", "si")
            .filter(str -> str.length() > 1)
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
        System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
do
re
ma
po
fa
si
doremapofasi
```

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the mechanisms behind the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

> A stream pipeline consists of a **source** (which might be an array, a
> collection, a generator function, an I/O channel, etc), zero or more
> **intermediate operations** (which transform a stream into another stream,
> such as filter(Predicate)), and a **terminal operation** (which produces a
> result or side-effect, such as count() or forEach(Consumer)). `Streams are lazy`; `computation` on the source data is `only performed when the terminal operation is initiated`, and source elements are consumed only
> as needed.

**The main conclusion:**

Operations on the data in the pipeline will be performed only **`if the terminal operation is initiated`**.

Stream without a terminal operation is perfectly valid from the compiler's perspective of view. It will compile, but it'll not be executed.

And what you have tried to print (`java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter@63961c42`) isn't a result, but the stream object itself.

To produce a result or side-effect Stream-pipeline must end with a terminal operation (`collect()`, `reduce()`, `count()`, `forEach()`, `findFirst()`, `findAny`, `anyMatch()` - which commented out in your code). Note, that `peek()` is an intermediate operation and confuse it with `forEach()`. You can use `peek()` as many time as need, which can be useful for debugging purposes.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String result = getStream()
                .filter(str -> str.length() > 5 && str.length() < 8)
                .findFirst() // that will produce a single result that may or may not be present
                .orElseThrow(); // action for the case if result is not present

        System.out.println("Single result: " + result + "\n");

        getStream()
                .filter(str -> str.contains("a"))
                .peek(System.out::println) // intermediate operation that will print every element that matches the first filter
                .filter(str -> str.length() > 8)
                .forEach(System.out::println); // terminal operation that prints every element remained after processing the pipeline
    }

    private static Stream<String> getStream() {
        return Stream.of("Ignoranti", "quem", "portum", "petat", "nullus", "suus", "ventus", "est");
    }
```

**output**

```
Single result: portum

Ignoranti
Ignoranti
petat
```

Comment: Yes, But i need to understand if there is any way where we can convert from resultant stream to String in java8

Comment: @Prasad You still don't understand. You don't have to `convert` stream to string, the stream can be written in such a way that it gives you a `result of its execution as a string`. Look at the first lines of code in the `main()` in my answer `findFirst().orElseThrow()` gives  a result a single string.

Comment: @Prasad If need a string or a list of strings you have to build a stream pipeline in such a way that it will give you that a product of its execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to only print the elements rather than getting them in return, you can just

```
Stream.of("do","re","ma","po","fa","si")
    .filter(str -> str.length()>5)
    .forEach(System.out:: println);
```

`forEach` is also a "terminating" operation on the stream, which means that it "actually executes" it.

Comment: Yes i can do it but what i want to know from my question is , there is a print statement in peek() and it returns some Stream object.. can we print those values by converting it to String

Answer (score -1):

you need to 'execute' the stream by calling collect or reduce

```
assertEquals("ab", Arrays.stream(new String[]{"a", "b"}).reduce("", (s,x) -> s + x));
```

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.joining())` would be more readable than `reduce` in this case

Comment: And more efficient.  The `reduce` is doing the equivalent of concatenating strings in a loop.

Comment: Why did you replace the question’s simple `Stream.of("a", "b")` with `Arrays.stream(new String[]{"a", "b"})`?